# Как сделать весь текст маленьким регистром?

Tags: godot

Я долгое время работал на питоне и знаю о методе `lower`, сейчас я работаю в `Godot Game Engine`, он использует `gdscript`(Язык самого движка), данный язык основан на синтаксисе языка питон и многое с него перенял.

Мне необходимо вывести содержимое переменной `(str)` маленькими буквами. Я по привычке ввожу `lower`, выдаёт ошибку. Посмотрел, погуглил, ответ не нашёл. Знает кто решение? Пример:

```
print(command.text)
>> RELOAD
print(command.text.method())
>> reload
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В документации написано:
`String` **to_lower ()** `Returns the string converted to lowercase.`

https://docs.godotengine.org/ru/stable/classes/class_string.html

Comment: Благодарствую, чего-то сам не нашёл

Comment: @АлександрСан-Андреас, используйте англоязычные доки. На русском я тоже не нашел.

Comment: Так-же пока тут, можете подсказать если знаете ответ на данный вопрос, какой в gdscript аналог питоновского split? А если есть возможность, то можно и ссылку кинуть

Comment: @АлександрСан-Андреас, юзайте доки пжлст https://godot-es-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/classes/class_string.html?highlight=split#methods

Comment: А как вы умудрились изучить godot? У меня что-то никак не получается.